# Change OpenID for Careers Site

Tags: support, jobs, openid

Is it possible to change the open ID for my careers.stackoverflow.com account?  I've done it for my primary stackoverflow.com account, but the careers site doesn't seem to behave the same way.

I've tried going to the account tab and clicking add openid, but it tells me that I'm already logged in and need to log out in order to use a different account.

Has anyone else been able to successfully change their OpenID provider for their careers account?

Comment: Does [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28708/let-me-use-multiple-openids-on-careers-please) help?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm - it seems that when we added the email/password login we inadvertently disabled the functionality to add/change openIDs. Thanks for finding that; we'll look into it. In the mean time, email me the openID you want to use at careers [at] stackoverflow [dot] com and we'll swap it out for you.

Comment: Is this planned at all or is it still a case of e-mailing you with the new OpenID?

Comment: @chrisf for now email me. Will update later with status.

Comment: I have just signed up for Careers 2.0, and it appears that this problem still exists. Any update?

Comment: @DavidNelson I was just able to add a google openID to an account that had only email and password login. What kind of openID did you try to add?

Comment: When I try to add my MyOpenID (commongenius.myopenid.com) to my careers.stackoverflow.com account (commongenius@hotmail.com), I see the following message:

Confirm OpenID
You are currently logged in.
Do you want to log out and log in as this OpenID?
https://commongenius.myopenid.com/

If I click Log In, I end up in an OpenID account that does not have a profile.

Comment: @DavidNelson You had an older account with that openid, which is why we couldn't add it... I've merged the accounts.

Comment: I have the same issue and I can't change my openid to a new one on Careers 2.0 (note that I done this on StackOverflow). @Korneel-Bouman it still a case of e-mailing to you with the new OpenID?

Comment: Agree with @Eduardo looks like nothing has been done in those 5 years, would be nice to have a way to change OpenID without emailing the team. (There is a link, but it's pointless since it only leads to a message/error).