# How to change Careers OpenID login?

Tags: bug, jobs, login, openid, google-openid

I created a new Google Account and I successful added the new one on my Stack Exchange account and after that I deleted the old one.

I tried to do the same for my Careers account, but the link "add OpenID" on my Carrers users page is not working and ask to logout with the message "But...but...you are already logged in.".

Seems that the functionality to add new OpenID to the account is not working.

Is there any way to do this OpenID change?

Comment: Yeah, the "add OpenID" is pointless now.

Comment: Anyway, according to [this old answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65384/152859), you should send your new OpenID details to the Careers team via email, guess it has not changed in those last 5 years.